# Is there a way to detect landing-area for autonomous landing using only opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

My Goals:
1- Detecting the  appropriate landing area for the drone using only image-processing in a known area

2- Detecting the objects and avoid from them while drone is landing.

I am trying to make an area detection for a drone autonomous landing in a known area. 
I've drawn a small marker as a rectangle for autonomous landing. But I want the system to draw this rectangle in random area where is appropriate for landing and this marker should not go over any object. If there is an object then will make another choice to detect area.

If you can't open images then you can use this link:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fHfE3IP0JKPNk8DpQaFXX4jk6mnEq3Xz

```
Created on Mon Oct 28 16:23:44 2019

@author: Veysel
"""

from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage.morphology import watershed
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np
import imutils
import cv2


img = cv2.imread('grass.jpg')
kernel = np.array([
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], # elliptical Kernel 5x5
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]], dtype="uint8")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)


hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

edge_low = np.array([ 30 , 25, 25])
edge_high = np.array([ 74 ,  255, 105])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_img,edge_low,edge_high)


imask = mask>0
green = np.zeros_like(img,np.uint8)
green[imask] = img[imask]

ret,th = cv2.threshold(gray, 177, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)



opening = cv2.morphologyEx(blur, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)


edges = cv2.Canny(closing,100,200)
dilation = cv2.dilate(edges, kernel, iterations=2)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)

cnt = contours[0]


area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

# Draw the contour 
img_copy = img.copy()
final = cv2.drawContours(img_copy, contours, contourIdx = -1, color = (255, 0, 0), thickness = 2)


draw = cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 2)

# The first order of the contours
c_0 = contours[0]

# Detect the convex contour
hull = cv2.convexHull(c_0)
img_copy = img.copy()
img_hull = cv2.drawContours(img_copy, contours = [hull], 
                            contourIdx = -0, 
                            color = (255, 0, 0), thickness = 2)

hierarchy = hierarchy[0] # get the actual inner list of hierarchy descriptions
for component in zip(contours, hierarchy):
    currentContour = component[0]
    currentHierarchy = component[1]
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(currentContour)
    if currentHierarchy[2] < 0:
        # these are the innermost child components
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
    elif currentHierarchy[3] < 0:
        # these are the outermost parent components
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)


mask = np.zeros(shape = img.shape, dtype = "uint8")

for c in contours:
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    cv2.rectangle(img = mask, 
        pt1 = (x, y), 
        pt2 = (x + w, y + h), 
        color = (255, 255, 255), 
        thickness = -1)
image = cv2.bitwise_and(src1 = img, src2 = mask)



color =(255,0,0)
x1 = np.random.random_integers(300) #I want this rectangle should be drawn
y1 = np.random.random_integers(300) # any area where is no objects
h1 = 50
w1 = 50

cv2.rectangle(green, (x1,y1), (x1+w1,y1+h1), color, -1)

cv2.imshow("FilterImage",image1)
cv2.imshow("DilationCanny",dilation)
cv2.imshow("HSV",hsv_img)
cv2.imshow("HSV2BGR",green)



cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Input_Image_Simplest_area_for_landing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr20D.jpg)

[Output_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvv7O.png)

Comment: Could you add your original input image and an expected output image?

Comment: Which is the expected landing area in your image?

Comment: I've added input and output(expected) images. You can see them on post. I can detect objects and draw a rectangle as a marker but this rectangle is drawn randomly. So it can be drawn over objects and I don't want it. I just want to detect object and select a safe area randomly for landing. And I want to use this safe area as a marker using rectangle.

Comment: If you can't open images then you can use this link:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fHfE3IP0JKPNk8DpQaFXX4jk6mnEq3Xz